# .NET & COM - Class_Terminate/Disposing of an object when it goes out of scope

Tags: .net, com, vb6, asp-classic

It is my understanding that for a VB6 COM object when it goes out of scope Class_Terminate is immediately called on the object to allow it to clean up.

Is it possible to have that same functionality for a .NET object that is being called by COM?

The background to the question is based on the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

This replaces the Session object in an ASP page with a custom object that serializes the Session information back to a database as soon as the page finishes by utilising Class_Terminate.

I want to implement the object in .NET, however as the GC won't call the finalizer immediately it is a bit of a problem, as I don't want to have to wait for the object to be cleaned up before being serialized back into the database.

I could just implement IDisposiable and manually call Dispose() when finished with the Session, but that would require altering every existing ASP classic page rather than just being able to include a few lines in a standard include file.

So is there a way to automatically call the code to do the work that is required when the page has finished? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegation. Wrap the .NET COM class in a VB6 Com Class that is a shell and in the Class_Terminate event of the wrapper call dispose.

If you don't want to reimplement the entire interface in the VB6 COM Class then you could do something like

```
Public MyNETCOMObject as MyNETCOMObject

Private Class_Initialize()
  Set MyNETCOMObject = New MyNetCOMObject
End Sub

Private Class_Terminate()
  If Not MyNETCOMObject = Nothing then MyNETCOMObject.Dispose
  Set MyNETCOMObject = Nothing
End Sub
```